# Why does nitrous oxide react with bases and it is still a neutral oxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have studied that N2O is a neutral oxide in my textbook(recommended by the central board of secondary education INDIA(country)). on internet and in my class notes i find its balanced reaction with NaOH. so it is neutral or is it an exception?
the reaction given is
N2O + 2NaOH -> 2NaNO +H2O

Comment: Could we see that reaction between $\ce{N2O}$ and $\ce{NaOH}?$ AFAIK there is none under ambient conditions. Also, what does "INDIA" abbreviate (countries are not written in all caps)?

Comment: You mentioned the reaction is balanced; the one you added is not, and to the best of my knowledge, doesn't occur (granted $\ce{NaOH}$ is in solution). Besides, what is "NaNO"?

Comment: i don't know the compound

Comment: Neither do I. $\vphantom{WTF}$

Comment: I agree with Andselisk, NaNO does not exist, and N2O does not react with NaOH in solution.

Comment: NaNO could be sodium hyponitrite, Na2N2O2.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hyponitrite) reports that an isomer of this salt could be synthesized by a reaction between sodium _oxide_ and nitrous oxide.

Answer (score 2):

Sad to see such glaring textbook errors. Nitrous oxide solubility in water decreases with increasing concentrations of NaOH. It does not react with NaOH to "form" NaNO.

Search this paper on Google and show it to your teacher.

J. F. Nunn, Respiratory Measurements in the Presence of Nitrous Oxide, Brit. J. Anaesth., 1958, 30, 254

[image: Paper]